# Empty array returned while fetching value from one column based on another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, data-science

There's a postgres db with table **'nlp'** having cols **'id'**(Integer), **'cycle'**(Integer), **'thresh'**(Numeric)

using *pd.read_sql* for reading the database.

`tb_data = pd.read_sql(rmdb.nlp, conn, columns = ['cycle','id','thresh'])`

tb_data is read correctly and is as follows:

```
             cycle                id                thresh
0               76                57                  85.0
1               55                38                  98.5
2               56                38                  98.5
3               57                38                  98.5
4               48                33                  98.5
..             ...               ...                   ...
65             159               125                  98.5
66             160               126                  98.5
67             161               127                  98.5
68             162               128                  98.5
69             163               129                  99.0
[70 rows x 3 columns]
```

then i tried to find the **'cycle'** value based on **id** using:
`tb_data.loc[tb_data['id'] == self.id, 'cycle'].item()`.
but i'm getting empty array and *.item()* is throwing error *can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar.*

Expected value : 163

I also tried
`int(tb_data[tb_data['id'] == self.id]['cycle'].max())`. But still no data was returned. It throws flaot NaN cannot be converted error.

*Note*: *self.id* is numeric and i printed it just before the above statements and it's value is **129** according to the current table data.

The thing is, when i try to run the same code on google colab after creating a dataframe from dictionary, it runs as expected. I am not able to find out the problem here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can select first value if always exist:

```
tb_data.loc[tb_data['id'] == self.id, 'cycle'].iat[0]
```

Or more general if possible returned empty `Series` is use `next` with `iter` for return first value, if `exist` else custom string, here `'no match'`:

```
next(iter(tb_data.loc[tb_data['id'] == self.id, 'cycle']), 'no match')
```

Comment: but the thing is tb_data.loc[tb_data['id'] == self.id, 'cycle'] is returning an empty array. So, there's no point of .iat[0]

Comment: @MaheshGupta - Oki, so use second solution.

Comment: that is also of no use because there's 'cycle' data mismatch if i set any default value to it and other part of code won't work. Point is the 'cycle' data persists in dataframe but it's not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake, i didn't checked the type of id which i was passing in the equality operataion. I was matching string with integer which was giving false and i was not able to get the cycle value.